# This.innerHTML на ссылку

Tags: javascript

Есть кусок такого кода:

```
<span onClick="this.innerHTML=''">
<div class="type1"><br>
  <b>#</b> &nbsp; </div>
<div class="type2"><br>
  &nbsp;<a href="#">link</a> </div>
</span>
```

В итоге получается столбец с порядковым номером и ссылкой.

Хочется, чтобы при клике на ссылку всё пропадало, сейчас же при клике в пустом поле — пропадает. Как можно получить желаемый эффект?

Comment: div внутри span? Советую поменять теги местами.

Comment: это второстепенно. именно тут верстка пока не важна. хочется добиться нужного эффекта: при клике на именно ссылку исчезает всё, но увы, чего-то не получается.

Comment: можно так: http://jsfiddle.net/ZaWbv/

а onclick в вёрстке лучше не использовать.

Comment: @Genson, а чем плох div внутри span?

Comment: @dzhioev потому что нельзя использовать блочные элементы внутри строчных. Наоборот можно, а так нет.